# Dynamically Transform Elements Relative to Other Elements in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to get the following in HTML/CSS (basically diagonal lines 'connecting' squares in the corner):

```
 ___________________
| |     /|    1    |
| |    / |_________|
| |   / /|    2    |
| |  / / |_________|
| | / / /|    3    |
| |/_/_/_|_________|
| |1|2|3_|_________|
|_|1|2|3_|_________|
```

Right now I am using divs and transforming them using a custom Angular directive (where I pass in the element it is trying to attach to), but I was wondering if there was an easier way to represent this?  It seems very JQuery-esque to me, and since I am new to Angular, I want to try to stray away from that.

Also, I want it to be dynamic, in case I want to add more boxes on either side, or if I want to resize the boxes or add other content, and so static CSS is out.

Here is my current attempt: http://plnkr.co/edit/XqwpRKlVqfVlwnA8KZ0f?p=preview (also, my side label doesn't seem to align in the center for some reason, no idea why...)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my directive to the following:
http://plnkr.co/edit/xyOBA6iCx4BPqjqBlPYN?p=preview

I removed the ids from the s and put them on the first :

```
<td id="row-1">1</td>
</tr>
<tr><td id="row-2">2</td></tr>
<tr><td id="row-3">3</td></tr>
```

I also added an id to the first rows:

```
<td id="col-1" width="34px">1</td>
<td id="col-2" width="34px">2</td>
<td id="col-3" width="34px">3</td>
```

The directive is now "draw-line," which basically uses math to determine the length:

```
var from_elem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#' + attrs.from ) );
var to_elem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#' + attrs.to ) );
var height_distance = from_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top-to_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
var width_distance = from_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().left-to_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
var distance = Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(height_distance,2)+
                Math.pow(width_distance,2)
);
var angle = Math.atan(height_distance/width_distance);
var my_current_border = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
var required_padding = (distance - my_current_border)/2;
element.css({
    'top':to_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px',
    'left':to_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px',
    'border-top': '1px solid',
    'position': 'absolute',
    'padding-left': required_padding + 'px',
    'padding-right': required_padding + 'px',
    'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'rad)',
    'transform-origin': 'left top'
});
```

So far it only works for top left to top left, if the from element is to the top right of the to element, but that is sufficient for me.

Is it angular-ish to select elements the way I did here?

```
var from_elem = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#' + attrs.to ) );
```

and then do the following to get the position?:

```
var height_distance = from_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top-to_elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```